# Missing DLL when trying to run Sibelius with WINE

Tags: wine

I am a new linux user and I tried installing Sibelius with WINE. Installing is successful however when I try to run it with wine nothing happens, so I tried running it through the terminal with wine, and then I get

```
LoadLibrary failed:  Check your system32 or SysWOW64 directory for AvidRemoteObjects364.dll
```

I tried copying the DLL from my desktop which has sibelius installed but I couldn't find it in neither system32 nor syswow64

I also tried installing and running it with wine start and here is what I got

```
002d:fixme:wer:WerRegisterFile (L"C:\\users\\boomer-remover\\Application Data\\Avid\\Logs\\startup.log", 2, 2) stub!
```

002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23f100 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23eb70 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23eb80 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:process:RegisterApplicationRestart (L"/restart",0)
002d:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
002d:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x23e690,0x00000000), stub!
002d:fixme:wgl:X11DRV_wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB unsupported 2008 WGL Attribute
002d:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
002d:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
002d:fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
0017:fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 74080 (device=7 access=1 func=20 method=0)
0017:fixme:mountmgr:query_property Faking StorageDeviceProperty data
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23e790 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23e890 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23e660 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x23e0c0 1 C) semi-stub
002d:fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
002d:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0xddf3c38) stub
002d:fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x3e6b78) stub

What do I do?

Comment: Does this help: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=31334 ?

Comment: I saw the post, and the "dumb hack" included, however I have no idea what to do, or how to install the hack? or anything at all, I just installed ubuntu last night

Comment: Did you get as far as "Installing the program with 'wine start' and running it that way seem to have fixed the missing DLL issue"?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to install it with wine start and also run it with wine start, didnt help though

Comment: however when I try to run it without wine start, and just with wine, I get the same error